# Why did BFD add euid=0 to APF IP deny_host.rules?

Tags: firewall

Trimming down some old deny_hosts today and I noticed this one:

```
# added euid=0 on 11/03/14 11:00:04 with comment: {bfd.sshd}
euid=0
```

Anyone know why the BFD would have added euid=0 root/permissions set to the APF deny_hosts.rules?

The only thing I noticed during that time period was a bot triggering logs at app level...somehow it had no IP detected (proxy sniffed). That is the only strange event that comes to mind during that time period. Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks!